# No colored dots under event dates in the Calendar indicator

Tags: wingpanel, calendar

I see no colored dots under the dates with events in the Calendar indicator. Is this a feature yet to come or am I missing a setting?

Here is a screenshot with the colored dots, which I don't have on my eOS Hera install:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is [here on Github](https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-datetime/issues/206). A solution is not there yet.

Comment: It's updated today, the dots are back!